# Automatic Layout

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.0, maps, layouts

I have a number of maps to generate. Only one shapefile is used where the Z-value is only the variable in differing maps. Is it possible to auto-generate maps using ArcGIS 10.0?

Answer (score 3):

Yes.

- [Data Driven Pages](http://help.arcgis.com/EN/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//00sr00000006000000) were introduced at ArcGIS Desktop 10.0:

> Data Driven Pages allow you to quickly and easily create a series of
>   layout pages from a single map document. A feature layer, or index
>   layer, divides the map into sections based on each index feature in
>   the layer and generates one page per index feature.

- [arcpy.mapping](http://Arcpy.mapping%20is%20a%20Python%20scripting%20module%20that%20is%20part%20of%20the%20ArcPy%20site%20package.%20It%20gets%20installed%20with%20ArcGIS%20Desktop%20and%20is%20available%20to%20all%20licenses.%20It%20was%20designed%20primarily%20to%20manipulate%20the%20contents%20of%20existing%20map%20documents%20(.mxd)%20and%20layer%20files%20(.lyr).%20It%20also%20provides%20functions%20to%20automate%20exporting%20and%20printing.) was also introduced at ArcGIS Desktop 10.0:

> Arcpy.mapping is a Python scripting module that is part of the ArcPy
>   site package. It gets installed with ArcGIS Desktop and is available
>   to all licenses. It was designed primarily to manipulate the contents
>   of existing map documents (.mxd) and layer files (.lyr). It also
>   provides functions to automate exporting and printing.

Comment: I have read about Data Driven Pages yesterday. My problem is it is not easy to create an index in my area of interest. I am interested in Indonesia, which is archipelagic. It is quite hard to create an index here given many islands so I have different region boundaries which is irregular compared to index layer. Can you suggest ways to go around this?

Comment: @user2543 Without having clearer details of what you are trying to accomplish, it is not possible for me to do so.  Please use the **edit** button beneath your question to revise it with additional details, or ask a new more detailed question.